# Migrate MultipartBody request to retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using `OkHttpClient` with an `IntentService` and the code I have (and it is working) is :

```
RequestBody rBody =  = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart(KEY, key)
                .addFormDataPart(DESCRIPTION, description)
                .addPart(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(IMAGE_TYPE),
                        imageFile))
                .build();

    Request uploadRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(rBody)
            .addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, MEDIATYPE)
            .build();
```

and what I have tried with retrofit 2 is :

The UploadService file :

```
@Multipart
@POST("new_post")
Call<ImageResponse> uploadImage(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType,
                    @Part("image") RequestBody imageRequestBody,
                    @Part("key") RequestBody apiKeyRequestBody, 
                    @Part("description") RequestBody descriptionRequestBody);
```

The request :

```
    uploadImageService.uploadImage(MEDIATYPE, 
            createRequestBodyForImage(uriPath),
            createRequestBodyForApiKey(),
            createRequestBodyForDescription(description))
            .enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
            // success/failure code here
```

and the functions for creating the `RequestBody`s are :

```
private RequestBody createRequestBodyForImage(String uriPath) {
    File file = new File(uriPath);

    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file);
}

 private RequestBody createRequestBodyForApiKey() {
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject()
                .put("key", Constants.API_KEY);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), jsonObject.toString());
}


// method for the description is same as above for api key
```

The thing is that with the retrofit way I get as a response : "wrong api key".
Since the key is the same as the one I'm using with the `IntentService` + `OkHttpClient`, is there something wrong with my request ?

Answer (score 1):

In Interface

```
        @Multipart
            @POST("forms/submit")
            Call<ResponseModal> sendRequest(
                    @Part("json")
                            RequestBody body,

                    @PartMap()
                            HashMap<String, RequestBody> mapFileAndName);
```

Put all images in HashMap

```
RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"), new File("/sdcard/file.jpg"));
 HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put(key + "\"; filename=\"" + key + ".jpg", reqFile);
```

put all parameter in Hasmap format

```
RequestBody json = createPartFromString(jsonString);
```

Now call api like this

```
  Call<ResponseModal> call = apiInterface.sendRequest(json, map);
```

Comment: OK let me try it and I'll let you know.

Comment: well tested code work perfectly with multiple image or a single image. JSON data should be handled in backend side